# Delta Dirac and duality property

Tags: education, dirac-delta

I know that the property of duality says:

$$x(t) \iff X(f)$$
$$X(t) \iff x(-f) "="x(t=-f)$$

and I know that:

$$\delta(t-t_0) \iff exp(-j2\pi ft_0)$$

If I apply the duality property, I get:

$$exp(-j2\pi f_0t) \iff \delta(-f-f_0)$$
$$exp(j2\pi f_0t) \iff \delta(f-f_0)$$

instead the correct result is:

$$exp(j2\pi f_0t) \iff \delta(f+f_0)$$

Why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess $exp(j2\pi f_0t) \iff \delta(f-f_0)$ is correct, while $exp(j2\pi f_0t) \iff \delta(f+f_0)$ is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between $t$ and $f$ , Duality says

> $$x(t) \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) \implies X(t)\Leftrightarrow2\pi x(-\omega) $$
>   Or in terms of $f$ 
>   $$x(t) \Leftrightarrow X(f) \implies X(t)\Leftrightarrow x(-f) $$

So for $\delta(t-t_0)$
$$\delta(t-t_0)  \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{exp}(-jt_0 2\pi f) \implies \mathrm{exp}(-jt_02\pi t) \Leftrightarrow \delta(-f-t_{0})=\delta(f+t_0)$$
And for $\delta(t+t_0)$ 
$$\delta(t+t_0)  \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{exp}(jt_0 2\pi f) \implies \mathrm{exp}(jt_02\pi t) \Leftrightarrow \delta(-f+t_{0})=\delta(f-t_0)$$
Note that $\delta(t)$ is even function

Please let me know if i can improve my answer somehow , thanks !

Comment: Hi @Lelouch.D.Light. Why did you write $2\pi x(-\omega )$? I know that $\omega = 2\pi f$, thus I expect $\frac{x(-\omega )}{2\pi}$.

Comment: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html#Symmetry see the proof on this page